# spark 2.0.2 ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer

Tags: maven, apache-spark, apache-kafka, classnotfound

Below is my pom.xml. I build the jar with maven shade. I am very sure with the org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer is included in my uber jar. Also I have put the kafka-clients-0.10.1.0.jar into spark spark.driver.extraLibraryPath.  I also tried add --jars option in spark-submit command. But I still get the classNotFoundException.

```
   <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
                <version>2.11.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>0.10.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just find a bypass solution. Add the jar into `SPARK_HOME/jars`.
I use `spark-submit` command. Tried add `--jars,--driver-library-path`. I am sure the options take effect. But still `classNotFound`. 
I find the bypass solution according to the driver log listed as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaQDs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```